# Como obtener la fecha de mi dispositivo android

Tags: java, android-studio

estoy tratando de obtener la fecha que hay en mi dispositivo android y mostrarla en un textView, sin embargo me aparece el siguiente error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
> android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Y no he descubierto porque, he buscado y me aparecio que era porque no tenia bien la referencia al TextView, pero según yo si la tengo bien, anexo el código:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Folio = findViewById(R.id.txt_Folio);
    Fecha = findViewById(R.id.txt_Fecha);

    obtenerFecha();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

private void obtenerFecha()
{
    try
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date currentDate = cal.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
        String date = df.format(currentDate);

        Fecha.setText(date);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

El metodo lo llamo desde el onCreate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu primer error está en que tienes mal acomodado tu código, debería ser así:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Folio = findViewById(R.id.txt_Folio);
    Fecha = findViewById(R.id.txt_Fecha);

    obtenerFecha();
}
```

Comment: Pues si era eso, muchas gracias por la ayuda